# Creating data.frame reprsenting grid points of all pairs of coordinates and corresponding Z to each paid of coordinates

Tags: r, sp

I have a `inter.spt` dataframe representing rainfall station's coordinates and elevation. I want to create a new `data.frame` containing a grid of all pairs of coordinates with corresponding `Z` of each pair of coordinates using `ExpandGrid` function.

I have achieved to create a grid data.frame containing all pairs of stations, but couldn't achieved to create the `Z` grid points.

The final data.frame that I want to get should contain a grid data.frame of `X, Y and Z`.

```
library(sp)
> setwd("F:\\OneDrive\\Master data analysis\\ThesisDataAnalysis")
> 
> Proj1 <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs "
> Proj2 <- "+proj=utm +zone=47 +a=6377304.063 +b=6356103.038993155 +towgs84=-11,851,5,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "

> inter.spt <- read.csv("processed//inter.spt.csv")  
> colnames(inter.spt) <- c("X", "Y", "Z") 

> head(inter.spt, 5)
         X        Y   Z
1 100.6903 6.340600  45
2 100.7722 6.240300 101
3 100.6125 6.254200  31
4 100.1855 6.448029   6
5 100.2407 6.444362   7
> 
> coords <- inter.spt[, 1:2]
> coords.spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords= coords, 
+                                       data = inter.spt, 
+                                       proj4string = CRS(Proj1))
> coords.spdf <-spTransform(coords.spdf, CRS=Proj2)
Warning message:
In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum unknown in Proj4 definition


> bbox(coords.spdf)
       min      max
X 625452.2 696045.8
Y 646774.1 712830.6
> 
> xmin <- 625452.2
> xmax <- 696045.8
> ymin <- 646774.1
> ymax <-  712830.6
> spa.res <- 100.00
> 
> #Create a grid of all pairs of coordinates (as a data.frame) using the "expand grid" function a
> x <-  seq(xmin, xmax, by = spa.res)
> y <-  seq(ymin, ymax, by = spa.res)
> xy <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)

> head(xy, 5)
         x        y
1 625452.2 646774.1
2 625552.2 646774.1
3 625652.2 646774.1
4 625752.2 646774.1
5 625852.2 646774.1
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Would "a grid of all pairs of coordinates" be six columns, x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2 over all pairs of points? Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english. I just want a grid points of three columns, X, Y, Z. Have a look on the last lines/portion of the code, I have X and Y, and want to get third column which is Z.

Comment: Okay, this is a spatial interpolation or smoothing problem. You have an irregular set of data points (x,y,z) and want to estimate the z values at locations (x', y') on a grid over the bounding box of (x,y). You need to look at kriging, inverse distance weighting, or any of a number of spatial smoothing or fitting options. Plenty have been described here now you know what to search for!

Comment: @Spacedman, your instruction has solved my problem. I interpolated the Z value using IDW in R environment. Thank you very much. You can close the question